# Is this true "If $f^{'}$ is continuous in $[a,b]$,then $f$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$"

Tags: calculus

I was doing a question on mean value theorem where it appears that author had used the fact that **"If $f^{'}$ is continuous in $[a,b]$,then $f$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$"**.I don't know if this is true.

Here is that question

> Suppose that $f''$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and that $f$ has three zeros in the interval. Show that $f''$ has at least one zero in $(a, b)$.

In the solution author is applying rolle's theorem on $f'$ without knowing $f'$ is differentiable/continuous or not.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you have it right? The very fact that $f'$ _exists_ in $[a,b]$ means that $f$ is differentiable by definition.

Comment: How do you define $f'$ when $f$ is not necessarily differentiable? Are you considering something like a.e.-derivative or distributional derivative?

Comment: @TonyK I have included question now

Comment: Are you looking for the result that differentiable implies continuous? The question implictly assumes that $f$ is twice-differentiable, so $f'$ is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: @anomaly Thanks

Comment: @TonyK I somehow missed the prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem starts by already supposing that $f''$ exists, i.e. that $f$ is twice differentiable. From this we know that $f'$ is differentiable, and thus also continuous.